# Универсальный репозиторий для работы с бд

Tags: c#, база-данных, ado.net

Здравствуйте. Решил написать свой абстрактный репозиторий без EF. Он будет содержать стандартные виртуальные методы(Add, Update, GetList и т.д.). И его буду наследовать к конкретным репозиториям классов. Может кто-то сталкивался с этим и может подсказать. Кажется, что я делаю ужасный велосипед, или просто не по тому пути иду.

```
abstract public class BaseRepository<T>
        where T : class, new()
    {
        public string TableName { get; set; }

        public BaseRepository()
        {
            this.TableName = typeof(T).Name;
        }

        public virtual List<T> GetList()
        {
            var lst = new List<T>();

            var da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + this.TableName + "]", Config.con);
            var dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
            {
                var item = new T();
                var type = typeof(T);

                foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
                {
                    var fieldName = prop.Name;
                    var fieldValue = dr[fieldName];

                    prop.SetValue(item, fieldValue, new object[] { });
                }

                lst.Add(item);
            }

            return lst;
        }

        public virtual void Add(T item)
        {
            var query = $"INSERT INTO [{TableName}](";
            var valuesQuery = $" VALUES (";

            foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                query += $"{property.Name},";
                valuesQuery += $"@{property.Name},";
            }

            query = query.Remove(query.Length - 1, 1) + ")";
            valuesQuery = valuesQuery.Remove(valuesQuery.Length - 1, 1) + ")";

            var fullQuery = query + valuesQuery;

            var cmd = new SqlCommand(fullQuery, Config.con);

            foreach (var property in item.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue($"{@property.Name}", property.GetValue(item));
            }

            Config.con.Open();
            var result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            Config.con.Close();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что это паттерн репозиторий, реализацию можно [подсмотреть тут](https://metanit.com/sharp/articles/mvc/11.php).

Comment: Правильно ли я понимаю @AlexKrass , что по вашей ссылке используется Entity. Мне необходимо сделать по-другому, а не просто public void Create(Book book)
    {
        db.Books.Add(book);
    }

Comment: цитата из первого же абзаца "Репозиторий позволяет абстрагироваться от конкретных подключений к источникам данных, с которыми работает программа, и является промежуточным звеном между классами, непосредственно взаимодействующими с данными, и остальной программой". В вашем случае просто реализация методов внутри другая.

Comment: А зачем вы используете: `SqlDataAdapter`, `DataTable`, `DataRow`, а потом их тут же убиваете при выходе из метода? Не легче ли тогда ради скорости и меньших затрат памяти использовать `ExecuteNonQuery()`, `ExecuteScalar()`, `ExecuteReader()`?

Comment: Все ж таки вам надо определиться какой режим `ADO.Net` вы используете: disconnected (`SqlDataAdapter, DataTable`) или же connected (`ExecuteXXX`), а еще подумать о том, что может потребоваться работать не с одной таблицей, а с двумя или даже тремя одновременно (сложные запросы). Вероятно, лучше всего выбрать первый режим, загружать данные из БД при создании экземпляра репозитория, отключаться от базы, держать в памяти `DataTable`ы, запрашивать из них, обновлять данные в них же,  а в заключении делать Commit(), т.е. сохранение в БД с помощью `SqlDataAdapter`

Comment: @Bulson, вот это по-настоящему дельно. Я настолько тупой, что вообще про возможность обновления бд через dataadapter забыл. Надо попробовать, спасибо)